# Playing a video after animation completed iOS

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, mpmovieplayercontroller

Well..I have a simple animation that slides 2 image views left and right.. when it's completed, I would like to play a video but with my existing code(below), animation never happens and video starts playing. How can I fix this problem? Thanks..

```
NSString *movpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testvideo" ofType:@"m4v"];
    mpviewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                        initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:movpath]];
    [mainView addSubview:mpviewController.view];



    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        leftView.frame = CGRectOffset(leftView.frame, 160, 0);
        rightView.frame = CGRectOffset(rightView.frame, -160, 0);
    }completion:(void (^)(BOOL)) ^{

        MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [mpviewController moviePlayer];

        [mp prepareToPlay];
        [mp setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
        mp.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

        [[mpviewController moviePlayer] play];

    }
     ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your completion block for the animation looks wrong. Try this:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        leftView.frame = CGRectOffset(leftView.frame, 160, 0);
        rightView.frame = CGRectOffset(rightView.frame, -160, 0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){

        MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [mpviewController moviePlayer];

        [mp prepareToPlay];
        [mp setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
        mp.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

        [[mpviewController moviePlayer] play];

    }];
```

Comment: Try placing  [mainView addSubview:mpviewController.view]; in the completion block.

Comment: I am getting the same result.